# Increasing the size of watermark text applied to an image

Tags: php, image, gd

I have this code:

```
<?php  

$filename   =  'Tulips.jpg';
$stringSize = 10000;
$footerSize = 40;  
$footer     = 'Blyxo.com/post/1234535';  

list ( $width, $height, $image_type ) = getimagesize ( $filename );  
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $filename );

imagefilledrectangle (  
        $im,  
        0,  
        $height,  
        $width,  
        $height - $footerSize, imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128));  

imagestring (
        $im,  
        $stringSize,  
        $width  - ( imagefontwidth ( $stringSize ) * strlen ( $footer ) ) - 2,  
        $height - $footerSize,  
        $footer,  
        imagecolorallocate ( $im, 255, 255, 255 ) );  

header ( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );  
imagejpeg ( $im ); 

?>
```

So; the image look like this:

[image]

But, I want to set the font bigger, but it doesn't works; i'm trying to set `$stringSize = 1000, $stringSize = 10, $stringSize= 9`, but (...) nothing.

And, if it possible, I want to know how to set the footer in the outset of the photo; not like a abolute position; in the outset.

Comment: `$stringSize` has to be between 1 and 5.  See <http://php.net/imagestring>:  "Can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for built-in fonts in latin2 encoding (where higher numbers corresponding to larger fonts) or any of your own font identifiers registered with imageloadfont()."

Comment: So, what I can do about this? to set the string bigger.-

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you have used this function... water mark set any angle,light or bright color in text,size..

Ref:http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php

```
imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )
```